# how can i change the recaptcha code in civicrm

Tags: drupal

I have installed civicrm in my drupal website. Now I want to change the recaptcha code 
provided by the Google.

How can i do this?

Please tell me some idea, or way of doing this.

Comment: Change it how? Switch to using a different captcha? Change the ReCaptcha API key?

Answer (score 1):

When you are logged in, go to CivicCRM and select Administer > Configure > Global Settings > Miscellaneous. You can enter your new code at the bottom of that page.